# Aggregate Function in R taking over 2 hours to execute

Tags: r, performance, aggregate-functions

I have used the following aggregate function in R to map unique values in column B with the corresponding unique values in column A. Is it normal that my code has been running for over 2 hours now without execution, given that my dataset contains around 2,50,00,000 rows

```
aggregate(colB~colA,df,function(x) toString(unique(x)))
```

Comment: Try the `data.table` version `setDT(df)[, toString(unique(colB)), by = colA]`

Comment: or try if it works for the first rows `aggregate(colB~colA,df[1:9999,],function(x) toString(unique(x)))`

Comment: but you should also get what you want with `unique(df[,c("colA", "colB")])`

Comment: I would try the ``data.table`` answer from Ronak Shah, generally, it really increase the speed of R in those situation. Also the ``aggregate()`` function can be demanding on R and your pc, so it can also depend of your computer spec while using medium-big data set. Edit: GKi answer is even simpler!